# Переход на новую строку в EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Подскажите пожалуйста почему нужный эффект срабатывает только через механическую клавиатуры. [скрин экрана](https://yadi.sk/i/65fu6XOOin2aMQ)

Разметка

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_input_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_show_photo"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/text_note_font"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:hint="@string/write_something"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                android:transitionName="text" />
```

EditorActionListener

```
detailBinding.etInputText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (detailBinding.etInputText.getText().toString().startsWith("1. ") && (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            nextNumber++;
            detailBinding.etInputText.setText(detailBinding.etInputText.getText() + "\n" + nextNumber + ". ");
            detailBinding.etInputText.setSelection(detailBinding.etInputText.getText().length());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переходить на новую строку у вас вместо:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

можно установить такое:

```
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|"
```

так же можно установить и такой аттрибут дополнительно:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

вот есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304163/new-line-when-user-press-enter-in-edit-text-in-android) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474321/enter-key-starting-a-new-line-in-edittext-instead-of-submitting-the-text-androi).

### UPDATE

вообще имелось ввиду использование такого слушателя:

```
field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0){}
        
   }
  });
```

то есть вы вводите текст и дальше разбираете его посимвольно, и когда введенный символ `== \n` то вы делаете перенос и добавляете вашу цифру. [Вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) по данному функционалу

Comment: дело в том что когда я выставляю android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|" у меня не срабатывает метод, после нажатия ок получается просто следующая строка без цифры 2. и тд.

Comment: я там немного ошибся, этот символ можно убрать в конце `|`, а по поводу цифр - вам нужно в слушателе поля смотреть какие символы вводятся и если новая строка то ставить номерок

Comment: переделал через editor все работает, но только через механическую клавиатуру

Comment: я немного отредактировал ответ, не очень понял что за механическая клавиатура) но в последней редакции логика тоже описана :)